# como fazer uma div aparecendo seguindo o cursor?

Tags: javascript, css

Boa tarde pessoal.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, estou criando um form de pagamento, tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(".spanhover").hover(function(event) {
    var divid = "#popup1"
    $(divid).css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();
}, function() {
    var divid = "#popup1"
    $(divid).hide();
});
```

```css
.credit-card-box .panel-title {
     display: inline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 .credit-card-box .form-control.error {
     border-color: red;
     outline: 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
 }
 .credit-card-box label.error {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 2px 8px;
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
 .credit-card-box .payment-errors {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 2px 8px;
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
 .credit-card-box label {
     display: block;
 }
 
 .credit-card-box .display-table {
     display: table;
 }
 .credit-card-box .display-tr {
     display: table-row;
 }
 .credit-card-box .display-td {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 50%;
 }
 
 .credit-card-box .panel-heading img {
     min-width: 180px;
 }
  
  .spanhover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
   
  <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                   <div class="panel-heading" style="min-height: 40px;">
                       <div class="col-md-7" >
                           <h3 class="panel-title display-td">Meio de pagamento</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-5">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-visa"></i><i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
                       </div>                    
                   </div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                     <h4>Dados do proprietário do cartão*</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Nome completo</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="text"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cardName"
                                              placeholder="Nome (conforme escrito no cartão)"
                                              autocomplete="cc-name"
                                              required autofocus 
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                          </div>
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">cpf</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cpf"
                                              placeholder="CPF"
                                              autocomplete="cpf"
                                              required 
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-4">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Nascimento</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="birthDate"
                                              placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                                              autocomplete="dt-nasc"
                                              required
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                    </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Número do cartão</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cardNumber"
                                              placeholder="Número do cartão"
                                              autocomplete="cc-number"
                                              required
                                          />
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardExpiry" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;"><span class="hidden-xs">Expira em</span><span class="visible-xs-inline">Data</span></label>
                                       <input 
                                           type="tel" 
                                           class="form-control" 
                                           name="cardExpiry"
                                           placeholder="MM / AA"
                                           autocomplete="cc-exp"
                                           required 
                                       />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                                <div class="popup" id="popup1" style="display:none;">test1</div>
                              <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardCVC" class="spanhover" id="hover1" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">CVC</label>
                                       <input 
                                           type="tel" 
                                           class="form-control"
                                           name="cardCVC"
                                           placeholder="CVC"
                                           autocomplete="cc-csc"
                                           required
                                       />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <p class="small btn-danger text-center">* estes dados não são armazenados.</p>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row" style="display:none;">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <p class="payment-errors"></p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Finalizar">
                        </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
                  </body>
                  </html>
```

A idéia era mostrar uma imagem de como encontrar o CVC no cartão, para isso colocaria isso em uma div que apareceria ao passar o mouse por cima do campo CVC, o resultado é que a div acompanhe o cursor enquanto ele estiver em cima da label, porém fiquei preso e daqui não consigo passar... alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Eu particularmente não vejo a necessidade de a div acompanhar o mouse pela label, até pq a label é pequena, só tem 3 letras.

Comment: Eu pretendo utilizar isto em outros pontos do sistema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta seria uma possível solução, basta substituir pelo que você precisar:

```js
 $( "#holder" ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        $("#popover").show().css({left:event.pageX, top:event.pageY } )
 })
 $( "#holder" ).on('mouseleave',function(){
 $('#popover').hide()
 })
```

```css
#holder{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
#popover{
  cursor: default;
  display:none;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br></br>
<div id="holder">
  <div id="popover">
    CVC
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando passa com o mouse sobre o #holder, adicionar a posição do mouse como offset do #popover e ao sair do #holder esconde-o.

Comment: Não funciona, jovem. Os pageX e pageY pegam a posição absoluta do cursor em relação a janela toda. É preciso fazer os tratamentos que citei na minha resposta.

Comment: Se vc adicionar uns `<br>` antes da sua div, vai ver que o popover vai aparecer bem longe do cursor.

Comment: Verdade, faltou tirar o position relative da div #holder

Comment: Agora melhorou!

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de usar `.hover`, que escuta dois eventos, `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, você precisaria usar dois eventos, `mousemove` e `mouseleave`. O primeiro fará o elemento acompanhar o cursor enquanto você move ele e o segundo irá ocultar a div.

Para que o cursor não fique por cima da div, adicione uma diferença nos valores da posição do cursor. No caso, adicionei `5px` no eixo X e subtraí a altura da div no eixo Y, porém ainda é necessário compensar a posição somando o valor do scroll da janela:

```js
$(".spanhover").on("mousemove mouseleave", function(event) {
   
   var divid = "#popup1";
   if(event.type == "mouseleave"){
      $(divid).hide();
   }else{
      var divid_height = $(divid).height(); // altura da div
      var scrolTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // scroll da janela
      $(divid).css({
         top: event.clientY-divid_height+scrolTop,
         left: event.clientX+5
      }).show();
   }
   
});
```

```css
.spanhover{
   cursor: pointer;
}
.credit-card-box .panel-title {
     display: inline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 .credit-card-box .form-control.error {
     border-color: red;
     outline: 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
 }
 .credit-card-box label.error {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 2px 8px;
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
 .credit-card-box .payment-errors {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 2px 8px;
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
 .credit-card-box label {
     display: block;
 }
 
 .credit-card-box .display-table {
     display: table;
 }
 .credit-card-box .display-tr {
     display: table-row;
 }
 .credit-card-box .display-td {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 50%;
 }
 
 .credit-card-box .panel-heading img {
     min-width: 180px;
 }
  
  .spanhover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
   
  <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                   <div class="panel-heading" style="min-height: 40px;">
                       <div class="col-md-7" >
                           <h3 class="panel-title display-td">Meio de pagamento</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-5">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-visa"></i><i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
                       </div>                    
                   </div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                     <h4>Dados do proprietário do cartão*</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Nome completo</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="text"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cardName"
                                              placeholder="Nome (conforme escrito no cartão)"
                                              autocomplete="cc-name"
                                              required autofocus 
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                          </div>
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">cpf</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cpf"
                                              placeholder="CPF"
                                              autocomplete="cpf"
                                              required 
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-4">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Nascimento</label>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="birthDate"
                                              placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                                              autocomplete="dt-nasc"
                                              required
                                          />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                    </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">Número do cartão</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <input 
                                              type="tel"
                                              class="form-control"
                                              name="cardNumber"
                                              placeholder="Número do cartão"
                                              autocomplete="cc-number"
                                              required
                                          />
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>                            
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardExpiry" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;"><span class="hidden-xs">Expira em</span><span class="visible-xs-inline">Data</span></label>
                                       <input 
                                           type="tel" 
                                           class="form-control" 
                                           name="cardExpiry"
                                           placeholder="MM / AA"
                                           autocomplete="cc-exp"
                                           required 
                                       />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                                <div class="popup" id="popup1" style="display:none;">test1</div>
                              <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="cardCVC"  id="hover1" class="spanhover" style=" top:-15px !important;
                   font-size:14px !important;
                   color:#5264AE !important;">CVC</label>
                                       <input 
                                           type="tel" 
                                           class="form-control"
                                           name="cardCVC"
                                           placeholder="CVC"
                                           autocomplete="cc-csc"
                                           required
                                       />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <p class="small btn-danger text-center">* estes dados não são armazenados.</p>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row" style="display:none;">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <p class="payment-errors"></p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Finalizar">
                        </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
                  </body>
                  </html>
```

Comment: Excelente, era exatamente o que eu precisava!